# Why doesn't any outline font formats use Bézier curve of 4th order or higher?

Tags: fonts, format, complexity-theory, bezier, curve

TrueType uses 2nd order, and OpenType uses 3rd order. Why not any higher?

Is that because they have too much time/space complexity of rendering? In that case, I'd like to know their complexity in big O notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't *design* with higher order Beziers, and that's still the most important aspect of creating a typeface. Having floating control points that influence the curve indirectly makes the job harder, not easier. So, while there is objective value in using cubic rather than quadratic curves (much better arc approximation, terser curve expressions, etc), there is no clear benefit in using quartic (or above) over cubic. In fact, some properties that can be relied on for quadratic/cubic don't apply to quartic or above, necessitating slow and cpu-intensive algorithms during the design phase, making them objectively worse to work with. As such, no one has proposed a system that allows for them.

As for the complexity: the worst case way to draw curves (naive flattening using `s` steps) has a complexity of `s` times (n-1) interpolations times (n-2) interpolations times etc. until the final interpolation yields our coordinate-at-`t` i.e. `s * n(n-1)/2` giving us a big O notation of O(n²).

Although some care should be taken here: at low `n`, a "good looking" curve will require a value of `s` that can be *considerably* bigger than n², so even though it's technically a constant, it's more useful to look at actual numbers rather than big O:

| order | coordinates | interpolations | number of interpolations to draw the curve | reasonable `s` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 2+1 | 3s | 8~16 |
| 3 | 4 | 3+2+1 | 6s | 16~32 |
| 4 | 5 | 4+3+2+1 | 10s | 32~64 |
| 5 | 6 | 5+4+3+2+1 | 15s | ... |
| 6 | 7 | 6+5+4+3+2+1 | 21s | ... |
| 7 | 8 | ... | 28s | ... |
| 8 | ... | ... | 36s | ... |

The higher the curve order, the more steps we need to make sure things look at least "reasonable".

Compare that to using "multiple low order curves":

| number of cubics | number of interpolations to draw the full curve |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 12s |
| 3 | 18s |
| 4 | 24s |
| 5 | 30s |
| 6 | 36s |
| ... | ... |

Diminishing returns: drawing higher order curves using cubic polyBeziers becomes *a lot* cheaper, *very fast*. For the same price of a single 8th order Bezier we can draw *six* cubic Beziers, and the resultant curve will be infinitely easier to manipulate when we want to tweak just a small part, too.

Comment: Your complexity is wrong. Computing a single point on a Bezier curve of degree n is merely O(n²) in a naïve implementation (successive interpolations) and possibly even faster with some clever tricks. Nowhere near exponential in n.

Comment: Oh shi- yes good point, let's update that a bit.